# Scipy is not showing correct eigenvalues?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to solve eigenvalues for M^-1 * K but getting wrong eigenvalues. What is the issue here? Correct eigenvalues should be : 3.17, 9.13, 13.98, 17.15

```
    from scipy import linalg
    import numpy as np
    

    M = np.diag([30,30,30,30])  # ton
    K = np.array([[5000,-2500,0,0],
                  [-2500,5000,-2500,0],
                  [0,-2500,5000,-2500],
                  [0,0,-2500,2500]
                  ])
    
    M_inv = linalg.inv(M)
    la, v = linalg.eig(M_inv @ K)
    
    print(la)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code computes the following for `la`:

```
In [82]: la
Out[82]: array([ 10.05122987,  83.33333333, 195.60802961, 294.34074052])
```

If we take the square root of these values, we see that `la` contains the *squares* of the values that you expected:

```
In [83]: np.sqrt(la)
Out[83]: array([ 3.17036747,  9.12870929, 13.98599405, 17.15636152])
```

So I suspect the problem is one of correctly translating the problem that you are solving into Python code and interpreting the result.

It looks like this is a vibration problem (with M the mass matrix and K the stiffness matrix of spring forces), and the equations that you implemented solve for the squared vibration frequencies ω², while the results that you expected are the frequencies ω.

Comment: thanks, i don't know how i missed that. thanks for the answer.